# data analysis for a partial two-by-two factorial design

Tags: anova

I need to analyze data generated from a partial two-by-two factorial design: two levels for drug A (yes, no), two levels for drug B (yes, no);  however, data points are available only for three groups, no drugA/no drugB, yes drugA/no drugB, yes drugA/yes drug B, omitting the fourth group of no drugA/yes drugB.  I think we can not investigate interaction between drug A and drug B, can I still run  model using R as usual:  response variable = drug A + drug B?  if yes,  how to explain coefficients for drug A and drug B?

Thank you very much!

Yuan Chun Ding

Answer (score 1):

You would not be able to assess the effect on "response" from  drug A alone but you would be able to assess the incremental effect of drug A+drug B (versus no drug) when compared to drug B alone (versus no drug). (So you would have half of an assessment of an "interaction".) Any further commentary would require that you better describe your data situation. Do you have measurements taken before and after drug or placebo were administered? Were these measurements perhaps taken in replicates? What is known about the reliability of the measurements of "response"?

As far as coding a model, I don't think you would use:

```
response variable = drug A + drug B
```

Rather I think you would form three categories for a single variable: `baseline`: 'no drugA/no drugB', `DrugA_alone`: 'yes drugA/no drugB', and `combA_B`: 'yes drugA/yes drug B'

Comment: Hi David, thank you so much for spending time on my problem!!  I also thought about running a one-way anova, but annoying that I have to run additional pairwise comparison to find out the pair showing difference if p value for one way anova is significant.